# Need identify path of my usb device

Tags: usb, python

Have any usb device

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:63e0 Microdia Sonix Integrated Webcam
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04f2:0841 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0525:3424 Netchip Technology, Inc.
```

and I need discovery path to device (`Bus 002 Device 007`) respond. I try send data to `/dev/bus/usb/002/007` but is not configured.

Which port should I send my data to communicate with usb device??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to access USB ports. I've only used it for regular RS232 serial ports myself, but at least for that it's easy to use and it's even been ported to python3 if you're using that.

You won't use the bus path like you said in your text, but rather use /dev/ttyUSBx where x is the number of your USB port. It's rather common to just iterate through ports 0-255 with PySerial and then catch the exceptions for ports that don't exist. Not sure if you would get the text identifier though. Like I said, I've never used it for USB myself so can't help you much on that end.

Comment: In my list of tty's not have `ttyUSB` only have `ttySx`. But I'm not undestand relation with `Bus 002 Device 007` and `ttyX` or `ttySx`. Have relation?

Comment: If you don't have any /dev/ttyUSBx then you haven't installed the device drivers for your USB device, I guess.

`sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0525 product=0xa4a6`

That could be the command to get it, according to [this page](http://www.fwma.de/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.OYO?color=orange).